# Write docm files using Python win32com and python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com, python-docx

Win32com only works on Windows operating systems and can process docm files.
However, python-docx works on all operating systems and cannot process docm files.

I want to process the docm file using the python-docx file on the Linux server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third-party components designed for dealing with `docm` files on Linux. For `docx` file you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) as it now supports .NET Standard which is supported by .NET Core on various distros of Linux.